# Finding out on which data path shard is located in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple `path.data`s configured for my Elasticsearch cluster.
The official documentation states that only a single path is used for a single shard, so it's never splitted across multiple paths.
I'd like to find a way to finding out which path on which node is used for some specific shard (primary or replica), like *index my-index primary shard 0* → *node RQzJvAgLTDOnEnmIjYU9FA path /mnt/data1*. Tried `/_nodes`, `/_stats`, `/_segments`, `/_shard_stores`, but there are no any references to paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find that info using the [indices stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-stats.html) by specifying the `level=shards` parameter

```
GET index/_stats?level=shards
```

will return a structure like this

```
  "indices": {
    "listings-master": {
      "primaries": {
        ...
      },
      "total": {
        ...
      },
      "shards": {
        "0": [
          {
            "shard_path": {
              "state_path": "/app/data/nodes/0",
              "data_path": "/app/data/nodes/0",
              "is_custom_data_path": false
            },
            ...
          }
       ...
```

Comment: Hello, Does it exist a way to have index name and data_path at once ?

Comment: @glmrenard I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily but but by doing a small python script I've the info I want, here the script

```html
import json

with open('shard.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print(data.keys())
data=data['indices']

for indice in data:
  #print(indice)
  d1=data[indice]
  shards=d1['shards']
  #print(shards,type(shards),shards.keys())
  for nshard in shards.keys():
    shard=shards[nshard]
    #print(shard,type(shard))
    for elt in shard:
      path=elt['shard_path']['data_path']
      node=elt['routing']['node']
      #print(repr(elt['shard_path']['data_path']))
      #print("=========================")
      print(indice,'\t',nshard,'\t',node,'\t',path)
```

They you obtain stuff like

log-2020.11.06       1       oxx          /datassd/elasticsearch/nodes/0

log-2020.11.06       0       oxx          /datassd/elasticsearch/nodes/0

log-2020.11.05       1       oxx          /datassd/elasticsearch/nodes/0